# Modo depuración de los nuevos navegadores no acepta document.getElementById() en mi caso ¿Porqué?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring, struts

Estoy trabajando con html, javascript, struts1, oracle11, jQuery, spring, tiles, etc... El caso es que trabajo con una aplicación ya construida en la que se me ha pedido que se adapte a todos los navegadores incluida la versión IE11, específico en lo de IE11 porque la aplicación solo funcionaba de forma correcta en IE8, ¡SOLO! ni en chrome ni en firefox ni en versiones más modernas de IE. El caso es que quitando algún que otro estilo de la aplicación que no he conseguido que se vea de forma correcta, todas las funcionalidades de esta van a la perfección exceptuando 4 pequeñas cosas.

En todas las ventanas uno de los cambios que me pedían los navegadores cuando depuraba por ellos era que al usar getElementById el valor entraba con referencia nula, volví a usar lo que se usaba hace unos años, document.all[] y la aplicación me va perfectamente, los únicos que no puedo corregir son algunos como el siguiente:

```
    function pintarTablaLM(){
    var url = "/t/ct002_mSelect.do?l=1"
    + "&cod_m=" + document.getElementById('cod_m').value
    + "&v=" + document.getElementById('v_seleccionada').value;

    var http = new AW.HTTP.Request; 
    http.setURL(url); 
    http.response = function(text){ 
        var cod_l;
        var cod_m;

        oTableLM.fnClearTable();
        while(text.indexOf("|")!=-1) {
            cod_l = text.substring(0,text.indexOf("|"));
            text = text.substring(text.indexOf("|")+1);

            oTableLM.fnAddData([cod_l]);
        }
    }

    http.request();   
}
```

Informo, como ven al principio de la función coge el valor de cod_minitramo usando getElementById, con doctype html4 funciona correctamente, con el 5 me salta el error de referencia nula, pongo all, y el error desaparece, pero no me llegan los datos a la tabla.

Quizás no sea este el problema, pero se que all quedó obsoleto y me parece mala práctica tener que cambiar algo moderno por algo antiguo cuando lo que quiero es modernizar la aplicación. ¿Alguna solución o idea de lo que pueda estar pasando amigos?

Este es el doctype que utilizo para html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`

EDICION DE LOS COMENTARIOS:

> @rnd así los tengo en código: `<html:hidden property="cod_m"/> <html:hidden property="v_seleccionada" />` >Y así aparecen en el depurador:     `<input type="hidden" name="cod_m" value="1">   <input type="hidden" name="v_seleccionada" value="2">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @rnd así los tengo en código: `<html:hidden property="cod_m"/> <html:hidden property="v_seleccionada" />` >Y así aparecen en el depurador:     `<input type="hidden" name="cod_m" value="1">   <input type="hidden" name="v_seleccionada" value="2">`

El problema radica en que el elemento no tiene dicho `id` sino que solo tiene el `name`, pero getElementById no funciona con la propiedad `name`.

La opción en struts es usar `styleId="el_id_aqui"`

Intenta esto, y utiliza getElementById

```
<html:hidden property="cod_m" styleId="cod_m"/> 
<html:hidden property="v_seleccionada" styleId="v_seleccionada"/>
```

esto dara como resultado en el html

```
<input type="hidden" name="cod_m" id="cod_m" value="1">  
<input type="hidden" name="v_seleccionada" id="v_seleccionada" value="2">
```

permitiendote usar `getElementById`